# How do I set the Linger socket option in C# when using a ZeroMQ QueueDevice (clrzmq)?

Tags: c#, multithreading, linq, sockets, zeromq

I'm trying to modify the ZeroMQ multi-threaded service example (http://zguide.zeromq.org/cs:mtserver) so that the sockets don't linger indefinitely on shutdown.  *I cannot figure out how to set the Linger value for the two sockets via the QueueDevice interface*.  In the other examples I've simply set the "Linger" option for the sockets and when the context shuts down they exited immediately.  In my current program the worker threads shutdown but the main thread hangs indefinitely... this might be as simple as using the SetSocketOption but I don't understand the LINQ syntax for this method (yet) and the "SocketOption" enum is not public.

**Note:** I'm using Visual Studio 2013 Express with 3.0.0-rc1 of clrzmq obtained via NuGet using the following command: `Install-Package clrzmq -Version 3.0.0-rc1`

**Usage:** Start the program and press "ENTER" to tell the main thread to shutdown and then wait for the workers to shutdown... but the main thread will block indefinitely.

Here is my code (Program.cs):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using System.Threading;
// add ZeroMQ via NuGet like this: Install-Package clrzmq -Version 3.0.0-rc1
using ZeroMQ;
using ZeroMQ.Devices;   // for queuing

namespace MTServiceCS
{
    class ThreadContext
    {
        public ZmqContext _zmqContext = null;
        public int _threadID = 0;
    }

    class Program
    {
        public static bool g_keepRunning = false;

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Starting MTServiceCS - multi-threaded hello-world - start the HelloWorld clients to test this server.");

            using (var context = ZmqContext.Create())
            {
                using (var queue = new ZeroMQ.Devices.QueueDevice(context, "tcp://*:5555", "inproc://workers", DeviceMode.Threaded))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Initializing Queue.");
                    queue.Initialize();
                    // TODO: how to set the "Linger" to zero?
                    // queue.BackendSetup.SetSocketOption(, 0);
                    // queue.FrontendSetup.SetSocketOption(, 0);

                    Console.WriteLine("Creating Threads.");
                    var workerThreads = new Thread[5];

                    // set to 'false' to tell the workers to shutdown
                    g_keepRunning = true;

                    for (int threadID = 0; threadID < workerThreads.Length; threadID++)
                    {
                        workerThreads[threadID] = new Thread(WorkerRoutine);
                        // passing in more than just the ZMQ Context
                        ThreadContext tc = new ThreadContext();
                        tc._threadID = threadID;
                        tc._zmqContext = context;

                        workerThreads[threadID].Start(tc);
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine("Threads created.");

                    Console.WriteLine("Starting Queue.");
                    queue.Start();

                    // we block here in the calling thread until "ENTER" is pressed and then try to shutdown...
                    Console.WriteLine("Press ENTER to shutdown.");
                    Console.ReadLine();

                    // tell the workers to exit, sleep and then exit... or die trying...
                    Console.WriteLine("Setting 'g_keepRunning' to false to tell workers to shutdown.");

                    g_keepRunning = false;
                    Console.WriteLine("HACK: Sleeping for 4 seconds to allow workers to exit");
                    Thread.Sleep(4000);

                    Console.WriteLine("Queue finished.");
                    queue.Stop();

                    Console.WriteLine("Stopping queue...");
                    if (queue.IsRunning)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Queue is NOT running.");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        while (queue.IsRunning)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Queue is STILL running? Looping waiting for it to close...");
                            Thread.Sleep(1000);
                        }

                        Console.WriteLine("Queue has stopped running!");
                    }

                    Console.WriteLine("Queue stopped.");

                    queue.Close();
                    Console.WriteLine("Queue closed.");

                }
                Console.WriteLine("QueueDevice closed.");

                Console.WriteLine("Exiting context...");
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Press ENTER to exit.");
            Console.ReadLine();

        }   // Main

        private static void WorkerRoutine(object threadContext)
        {
            ThreadContext tc = (ThreadContext)threadContext;
            ZmqSocket receiver = tc._zmqContext.CreateSocket(SocketType.REP);

            // ZmqSocket receiver = ((ZmqContext)threadContext).CreateSocket(SocketType.REP);
            receiver.Connect("inproc://workers");
            Console.WriteLine("Thread# " + tc._threadID.ToString() + " starting.");
            // Console.WriteLine("Thread# starting.");

            // 1-second timeout
            TimeSpan tsTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);

            while (g_keepRunning)
            {
                string message = receiver.Receive(Encoding.Unicode, tsTimeout);

                if (message != null && message.Length > 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Message received: " + tc._threadID.ToString() + ": " + message);
                    Thread.Sleep(1000); // simulate our work here w/ a sleep for 1 second
                    // receiver.Send("World", Encoding.Unicode);
                    receiver.Send("World[" + tc._threadID.ToString() + "]", Encoding.Unicode);
                    // Console.WriteLine("Thread# " + tc._threadID.ToString() + " sending.");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("No message received: " + tc._threadID.ToString());
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Thread# " + tc._threadID.ToString() + " exiting.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've kept playing with this and if I replace the using around the Context and just exit the application w/o terminating, etc. I can get the app to exit... but that's just an ugly exit and won't work if I want to reset the app within the same context.

Comment: I tried adding what I think is a valid LINQ expression to try and set the Linger value but they didn't seem to matter.  The changes are: `System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<ZmqSocket, TimeSpan>> _linger = p => p.Linger;` and `queue.BackendSetup.SetSocketOption(_linger, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));`

Comment: It was mailing regarding the current state of clrzmq project. http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.network.zeromq.devel/21312 Perhaps you'd better try netmq https://github.com/zeromq/netmq

Comment: Thanks Sergey, I'll check out netmq.